# Changing font of a hypertext pdf without messing up the hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, text-formatting, hyperlink

I have a pdf with hyperlinks, I can click on the footnotes popup and be taken to them, when I open the pdf to change font in word, the resulting pdf has the popups in blue still but they're not clickable. I was wondering if there is any way to achieve that.

Note- M.S word needn't be part of the solution, any way to achieve the above would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A link and the text are two separate items in PDF, the text is part of the page, the Link is an annotation. The fact that the text is blue isn't because it's a link, its because the text is drawn in blue. Sounds to me like opening the PDF in Word (and resaving it) drops the annotations. Use a better editor or, better yet, go back to the original document, edit that and remake the PDF. PDF files are not meant to be editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing a PDF into Word it will apply its own Page Breaks (PDF does not have those), Page Layout and add margins (PDF does not have those either), Fonts, styles and references. Generally this means displacement of contents, differing appearances and lack of PDF imbedded features such as TOC (outline), some annotations and Links.

Here the footnote on Page 1 has been re-flowed onto Page 2 and none of the blue underlines are links, so need replacement in the Word document.

To retain PDF Paged abilities you would need to edit in a Full Editor such as Adobe Acrobat Standard / Pro, or one of their other PDF Page based designer editing products.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to edit without breaking annotations. But I wanted to do it for a pdf with hundreds of pages, I suppose I would have to look for a bash script or some equivalent.